# How can we understand what data structure is needed?

Tags: data-structures

Suppose I am trying to design an algorithm to solve a problem.

How should I proceed?

How can I understand what data structure is appropriate to solve my problem?

When trying to design an algorithm to evaluate an infix expression I thought it would be appropriate to use two stacks to solve the problem. But later I found that tree is needed to do the job.

How did the implementer come to know that tree would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Understand the problem.

Second: Identify your storage, search and logic requirements.

That is usually enough to understand what data structures are required and appropriate.

Beyond that, your question is too general, and contains too little information to answer more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

There's no rule of thumb. For your particular problem a completely new data structure might be needed. This often happens in AI problems, which is why Lisp was such a handy language because it was easy to construct new data structures from lists. (or actually s-expressions, which are equivalent to trees).

But most problems you encounter in the working world are much more mundane, and can easily be solved with a standard data structure. After a while you begin to associate certain problems with certain solutions (get something fast? a hash table. get something fast but also have some ordering requirements? a tree) and can decompose a more complex problem into simpler components that can be solved with these type of standard data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly understand the situation properly then think which is the most suitable in this problem. Suitable means which is fast and takes less memory.